# Deep matching template files in subfolders

Tags: go

I have this structure:

`./src/main.go`:

```golang
package main

import (
  "log"
  "net/http"

  "github.com/djviolin/lanti-mvc-gtpl/src/controllers"
)

func main() {
  http.HandleFunc("/", controllers.Index)

  err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
  }
}
```

`./src/controllers/index.go`:

```golang
package controllers

import (
  "html/template"
  "log"
  "net/http"
)

// Index : frontpage handler
func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  t := template.New("index")
  render, err := t.ParseGlob("./views/*.html")
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Parse: ", err)
    return
  }
  render.Execute(w, map[string]string{"Title": "My title", "Body": "This is the body"})
}
```

And I have the following template file's structure:

```
│   index.html
└───partials
        footer.html
        header.html
```

How can I deep match the partials in the subfolder? `ParseGlob` not supporting the `**` operator as far as I know. Is there a way to achieve this with the standard library templates?

**Update:**

I tried to use `github.com/mattn/go-zglob` (recommended under [this](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11862#issuecomment-181904656) github issue) for recursively list all template files in the `views` folder:

```
matches, err := zglob.Glob(`./views/**/*.html`)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Parse: ", err)
    return
}
fmt.Println(matches)
// RETURNS: [views/index.html views/partials/footer.html views/partials/header.html]
```

Which is returning a string array, however `ParseFiles` function needs `string` input separated with `,` commas, and because of that, the following code throwing this error:

```
message: 'cannot use matches (type []string) as type string in argument to t.ParseFiles'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution [here](https://github.com/siongui/userpages/blob/master/content/articles/2017/02/13/go-template-parse-all-files-in-directory%25en.rst). If anyone have a better idea than this, I highly welcome!

```golang
package controllers

// github.com/djviolin/lanti-mvc-gtpl/src/controllers/index.go

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

// GetAllFilePathsInDirectory : Recursively get all file paths in directory, including sub-directories.
func GetAllFilePathsInDirectory(dirpath string) ([]string, error) {
    var paths []string
    err := filepath.Walk(dirpath, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        if !info.IsDir() {
            paths = append(paths, path)
        }
        return nil
    })
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return paths, nil
}

// ParseDirectory : Recursively parse all files in directory, including sub-directories.
func ParseDirectory(dirpath string, filename string) (*template.Template, error) {
    paths, err := GetAllFilePathsInDirectory(dirpath)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    fmt.Println(paths) // logging
    t := template.New(filename)
    return t.ParseFiles(paths...)
}

// Index : is the index handler
func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    render, err := ParseDirectory("./views", "index")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Parse: ", err)
        return
    }
    render.Execute(w, map[string]string{"Title": "My title", "Body": "This is the body"})
}
```